# WordPress Crashes When Attempting to Edit Contribution Pages

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page

I am using CiviCRM 5.53.0 and WordPress 6.0.2. I have recently upgraded CiviCRM.

After upgrading I can no longer edit Contribution Pages. When editing I get:

"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

This happens when try to use any of the editing options.[image]

Yesterday, when I wrote this issue I was not getting any error in the ConfigAndLog folder. However, I tried again tonight before listing that I was not getting logs in this location and now I am.

I see:

```
Oct 03 00:33:49  [info] inactive contribution page access attempted - page number 3

Oct 03 00:33:49  [error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "The page you requested is currently unavailable."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Contribute_Exception_InactiveContributionPageException {#6424
    -id: 3
    #message: "The page you requested is currently unavailable."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php"
    #line: 322
    trace: {
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php:322 {
        › if (empty($this->_values['is_active'])) {
        ›   throw new CRM_Contribute_Exception_InactiveContributionPageException(ts('The page you requested is currently unavailable.'), $this->_id);
        › }
      }
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php:77 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:668 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:76 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php:380 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:356 { …}
      do_shortcode_tag() {}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:228 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php:227 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:307 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:331 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:524 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:787 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1330 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16 { …}
      /home/user/public_html/index.php:17 { …}
    }
  }
]

Oct 03 00:33:49  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Contribute_Exception_InactiveContributionPageException))
#2 /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(380): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#4 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->render_single((Array:2), "", "civicrm")
#5 [internal function](): do_shortcode_tag((Array:7))
#6 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback("/\[(\[?)(civicrm)(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\...", "do_shortcode_tag", "[civicrm component=\"contribution\" id=\"3\"]")
#7 /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(227): do_shortcode("[civicrm component=\"contribution\" id=\"3\"]")
#8 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->prerender(Object(WP))
#9 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#10 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(524): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#11 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(787): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#12 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1330): WP->main("")
#13 /home/user/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#14 /home/user/public_html/index.php(17): require("/home/user/public_html/wp-blog-header.php")
#15 {main}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which log files (in which locations) are you checking?

Comment: Can you check Civi log or php error log?

Comment: I found the log but I could still use some help you are able.  Thanks, Josh!

Comment: Okay, so I assume this happening on the front end of your website because the code is running through `do_shortcode_tag()`. And when it says "inactive contribution page access attempted" is that correct when you look in the CiviCRM back end?

Comment: @ChristianWach, I saw the same thing and I did not know what to make of it.  I am trying to access the edit page from the backend (wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fcontribute&reset=1).  I have all the buttons and appear to have permission for the operation I am trying to complete.  Thanks!

Comment: @Josh So I've tried to replicate this but can't... If I make a Contribution Page inactive, then I do see those log entries when trying to access that Contribution Page via a Shortcode in a WordPress Page. I don't get fatal errors on the back end, however, so the two must be unrelated. Can you check your general PHP log file?

Comment: @ChristianWach, I have an error_log file in the public_html folder but this only has deprecation warnings in it. Getting my extensions updated for PHP 8 and switching over the server. I just started to disable extensions I do not need any more and I took off Grant Applications(https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/grantapplications) . Everything started to work after removing this extension.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @ChristianWach!

Comment: Ah, glad it's sorted @Josh -weird that there weren't any error log entries though. Perhaps you need to write your own answer and accept it?